# Conditional grouping according to mean of specific rows comparing to a threshold

Tags: r, row, grouping, mean, threshold

I have a data set named `MyData` as below

```
     A         B         C           D           E 
1  yellow      X        0.8         52          0.4
2  yellow      X        0.5         116         1.5
3  yellow      X        0.4         23          0
4  yellow      Z        0.6         46          0.6
5  yellow      Y        0.2         230         3
6  green       X        0.3         1500        19
7  green       Y        0.1         15          0
```

I want to group the first and second row as a group, divide their average of `E` by their average of `D` and comparing the result to a threshold `0.01`. (For example: `((0.4+1.5)/2)/((52+116)/2)=0.011309524`, comparing `0.011309524` with threshold `0.01`).

(1)  If the result is larger than threshold 0.01, then we say the first and second row successfully form a group with group number `1`. We need output the group number, `A`,`B`,`C`, mean of `D`(row1 and 2) and mean of `E` to a new dataset named `MyData2`. Then start again from grouping the 3rd and 4th row to compare the calculation result with threshold `0.01`. If succeed again, we assign Group number `2` to row 3, row4 and output it to `MyData2`.

```
MyData2
      Group NO.       A         B         C           D           E 
1      1            yellow      X        0.8          84         0.95
2      1            yellow      X        0.5          84         0.95
```

(2) If the result come from row 1 and 2 is small than threshold `0.01`, we say the first and second row fail to form a group. Then we need to divide the average of `E` by the average of `D` for row 1, row2, and row 3. (That means group the first 3 rows together and calculate `((0.4+1.5+0)/3)/((52+116+23)/3)` and comparing it to the threshold `0.01`)...if grouping "successfully", assigning Group number `1` to row 1, row2, and row 3 and output the value mentioned above to `MyData2`. If still failing to form a group, we need to divide the average of `E` by the average of `D` for row 1, row2, row3 and row 4....until succeed.

My desired output:

```
MyData2
      Group NO.       A         B         C     Group_Mean_D     Group_Mean_E 
1      1            yellow      X        0.8          84           0.95
2      1            yellow      X        0.5          84           0.95
3      2            yellow      X        0.4         99.67         1.2
4      2            yellow      Z        0.6         99.67         1.2
5      2            yellow      Y        0.2         99.67         1.2
6      3            green       X        0.3         757.5         9.5
7      3            green       Y        0.1         757.5         9.5
```

My actual dataset has around 100 rows.

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* pretty.  Since the grouping is dynamic, I don't see any way to avoid loops in this problem, although I'd love to see someone succeed. I'm using a suite of packages called `tidyverse` to do this.  One of its features is the pipe operator, `%>%`.  If you aren't familiar with it, it takes the output from the last operation and plugs it in as the first argument of the next.  It lets me put actions sequentially instead of nesting them.

```
MyData2 <- MyData %>%
  mutate(
    one = 1,
    index0 = cumsum(one),
    index = index0,
    GroupNo = NA_integer_,
    Group_mean_D = NA_real_,
    Group_mean_E = NA_real_,
    result = NA_real_,
    keep = NA
  )

i <- 1L

while (sum(is.na(MyData2$GroupNo)) > 0) {
  working_data <- filter(MyData2, is.na(GroupNo))

  working_data <- working_data %>%
    mutate(
      GroupNo = i,
      index = cumsum(one),
      Group_mean_D = cumsum(D) / index,
      Group_mean_E = cumsum(E) / index,
      result = Group_mean_E / Group_mean_D,
      keep = result > 0.01 & index > 1
    ) %>%
    filter(index <= which(keep)[1])

    i <- i + 1
    MyData2[working_data$index0,] <- working_data
}

# Clean-up
MyData2 <- MyData2 %>% select(GroupNo, A:C, Group_mean_D, Group_mean_E)
```

Comment: When I run the "while"part...it shows error as below:
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'.
Calls: %>% ... as.data.frame -> mutate -> mutate.tbl_df -> mutate_impl -> .Call

Comment: Hmmm... I did get it working on my computer without issue.  That error usually means that a function is trying to be placed where a number is expected.  Are you running this exactly as I have it, or did you need to modify it some?  If you modified it, please post what you did.

Comment: Thank you very much...I revise the calculation of result and the value of threshold as below:       result =  sqrt((1-Group_mean_E/Group_mean_D)/Group_mean_E),
      keep = result < 0.4 & index > 1

Comment: I'm not seeing anything that would cause the error there.  Can you step through the while loop one element at a time and see exactly what calculation is causing the problem?

Comment: It seems that this works. However, I found that if all rows are fail to form a group(therefore no any group number assigned to those rows), the while loop will not have an end. Could you please let me know if you have any idea to avoid this error?...Thank you very much!

Comment: How should the algorithm behave in this case?  Probably, you need an if/else statement (pseudo-code: `if (all(!keep)) {do something else} else {current filter / assignment steps}` - but you need to decide (and be clear about) what the code should do before asking for more help.